# Trying to parse the HTML data from an open page in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a webpage that is currently open and requires authentication by username and password. With this page open, I want to read a counter on the page using BeautifulSoup. The problem is that the python libraries create a new instance and it again requires password, cookies, etc. See my short code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
# something like requests.get("current website") would be nice
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
# url.close()
```

It opens a new instance of the webpage and names it url and bs4 does the rest. Is there a way to avoid a new instance and parse/read from an existing webpage? I saw something similar on this site but it opened a new instance.

Comment: Just save the web page locally, then pass its location to the `BeautifulSoup` instantiation.

Comment: You need to send the session cookie in `requests.get`

Comment: `requests` doesn't know anything about your browser session with the web site. This doesn't work for the same reason that you need separate logins for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I want to read a counter so my data changes in time. I do not think a copy will refresh. If I try to send the session cookie, I get a response that my browser is not secure or something. I see that requests will likely not work but I was hoping that something similar would.